# Is there a standard way to recommend other packages in setup.py?

Tags: python-packaging

In `setup.py` one can use the `install_requires` key to list mandatory dependencies of a package.

Is there a way to **recommend** the installation of other packages here, even if they are not **required** for the package to work?

I'm thinking about something similar to debian's `apt` which makes a distinction between these two cases.